# this.array.ForEach dependencies not found with VueCLI

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, vue-cli

This is my code. I am using VueCLI.

The line that is creating a problem is `this.slides.forEach(..`

The error that I have is  `dependencies not found` (full error below).

When I install the dependencies missing `npm install --save core-js/modules/es.array.for-each core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each` I have a `es.array.for-each does not contain a package.json file` Error

I then created the package.json file in the location described in the error. I run `npm install` but I have the same `package.json not found` error.

Any clue of what is wrong here?

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <slot>

        </slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data (){
        return{
            index: 0,
            slides: []
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.slides = this.$children

        this.slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
            slide.index = i
        })
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">

</style>
```

```html
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                 10:39:10 AM
These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/modules/es.array.for-each in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Carousel/Carousel.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Carousel/Carousel.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es.array.for-each core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each
```

```html
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "core-js\modules\es.array.for-each" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     User\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-15T15_49_17_958Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

`npm install --save-dev @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global core-js@3`

did the trick! I think there are some issues with core-js@2

Comment: It's odd, because this is not supposed to be necessary. It started happening to me too, and I don't know why. It's a NodeList I'm iterating over (selected with `querySelectorAll`) with `forEach`.